# NX Nrwl build package Version number of Apps/Libs is allways 0.0.1

Tags: reactjs, nrwl, nomachine-nx

How to set the version of an NX App/Library build.
If i ran `nx build` or `nx affected` or `nx build:MYAPP or Lib (if publishable)` the version end allways as 0.0.1 and is not in sync with the version if the main package.json
which is even not clever if publishing apps + libs and some are not affected.

I tried nx Semver Plugin, which tags the build with a correct tag but the build (prod or not) ends as 0.0.1. ??

I found the azure/gitlab CI example there is nothing related to a package/version
But for CI we need allways a new package version!

As the docu lacks ...docu ...
HOW?

Answer (score 0):

isn't possible.

Possible solutions are

1. create a package.json per App/Lib
   Maybe not the best idea as it turns the idea of NX Monorepo upside down
2. Write a postTarget "Hook" to update the package.json after a successful version creation via a npm node script using `git describe --tags` to get latest version. and `npm version ${version}` to update package.json.